# Creating tar.gz in dist folder with python setup.py install

Tags: python, pypi

I have a project for which I want to create a tar.gz with `python setup.py install`.

Problem is, I only get egg files in my `dist/` folder when running `python setup.py install`. I need the project.tar.gz file so that I can easily make it installable from conda.

How do I make `python setup.py install` create a tar.gz (I do not need any egg files, really).

What I ultimately want is a tar.gz archive showing on pypi with a download link and md5, which I used to get before the PYPI update.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`python setup.py sdist` creates .tar.gz source archive and doesn't create eggs. That's probably what you want instad of `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Unfortunately on my Ubuntu20.04, this doesn't create .tar or .zip. Basically it seems to create and remove the archive: `creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'mypackage-1.0' (and everything under it)
`

Comment: @Peaceful It is in the directory `dist/`

Comment: Thanks so much. Also, could you have a look at this question from me? I have set a bounty of 500 on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64950460/link-f2py-generated-so-file-in-a-python-package-using-setuptools