# Link f2py generated *.so file in a python package using setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, fortran, shared-libraries, setuptools, f2py

I wish to deploy a package to PyPi using setuptools. However, the core part of the package is actually written in Fortran, and I am using f2py to wrap it in python. Basically the project's structure looks like this:

my_project

- license.txt
- README.md
- setup.py
- my_project

  - **init**.py
  - myfunc.py
  - hello.so

The module myfunc.py imports hello.so (`import my_project.hello`) which can then be used by functions inside myfunc.py. This works perfectly on my machine.

Then I tried standard setuptools installation: `sudo python3 setup.py install` on my Ubuntu, and it gets installed perfectly. But unfortunately, while importing, it throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'`.

Now, from what I understand, on Linux based systems, for python, the shared libraries *.so are stored in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`. So I manually copied this `hello.so` there, and I got a working package! But of course this works only locally. What I would like to do is to tell setuptools to include `hello.so` inside the python-egg and automatically do the copying etc so that when a user uses `pip3 install my_package`, they will have access to this shared library automatically. I can see that numpy has somehow achieved that but even after looking at their code, I haven't been able to decode how they did it. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you happy for this to only function on Linux or does it have to work on Windows and Mac as well? Can it only work on the (most common) x86_64 CPUs or does it have to work on i686 too?

Comment: @FiddleStix If it works on Windows and Mac, it would be great but I don't insist on it. Also, x86_64 is sufficient.

Comment: Just to be certain, you would like to pre-compile the f2py module so that users do not need a Fortran toolchain themselves (but implying all Fortran related dependencies need to be statically compiled into the .so, (.dll, or .dylib) by you, in advance, for all platforms you intend to support)? Or is it an option to make the f2py compilation part of the install process?

Comment: @jbdv Either is fine with me. I am happy to compile and ship, but then those .so should automatically get installed at appropriate places on user's machine. Otherwise, it is also fine that user compiles, generates .so and they get placed at appropriate place from where they could be imported by my package.

Comment: I use a setup based on a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8510633/3967096) where you commented. Does this not work for you? For a local install (`sudo python -m pip install .`), it places the .so file at `.../site-packages/my_project_f90.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` at the same level as other project files e.g. `.../site-packages/my_project-0.1-py3.6.egg-info`. This same structure is reproduced when creating a wheel distribution e.g. `sudo python setup.py bdist_wheel` in `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel`. Is this what fails for you?

Comment: @jbdv : It did work for me initially but when I tried it on other machines with linux and Mac, the package fails to load the submodules. Why should that work on one machine but not others. I even checked the python-egg after installation, and on some machines, it doesn't contain submodule directories.

Comment: Did you install from local sources or PyPi on the other machines? It may need a minimal reproducible example project to identify and solve the problem.

Comment: @jbdv : so far I have tried two things locally: `sudo python3 setup.py install` and `sudo python3 -m pip install .` .  Both seem to work as in I can import the package and the subpackages in the interpreter etc. However, these don't work on another machine where I have Ubuntu18.04. My package contains a submodule `test` which is not installed by these commands and while importing the main package, that throws error. If we could chat in the chatroom, I could show you the details. Thanks so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225146/discussion-between-jbdv-and-peaceful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach based on [F2PY's documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/distutils.html) (the example there covers building multiple F2PY modules, and multiple source files per module), making use of `numpy.distutils`, that supports Fortran source files.

The structure of a minimal example with multiple F2PY extension modules is based on a [`src` directory layout](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/). It is not necessary/required, but has the advantage that the test routine cannot run unless the package has been installed successfully.

#### Source layout

```
my_project
|
+-- src
|   |
|   +-- my_project
|       |
|       +-- __init__.py
|       +-- mod1.py
|       +-- funcs_m.f90
|       +-- two
|           |
|           +-- pluss2.f90
|           +-- times2.f90
|
+-- test_my_project.py
+-- setup.py
```

- setup.py

```py
from setuptools import find_packages

from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension

ext1 = Extension(name='my_project.modf90',
                 sources=['src/my_project/funcs_m.f90'],
                 f2py_options=['--quiet'],
                )

ext2 = Extension(name='my_project.oldf90',
                 sources=['src/my_project/two/plus2.f90', 'src/my_project/two/times2.f90'],
                 f2py_options=['--quiet'],
                )

setup(name="my_project",
      version="0.0.1",
      package_dir={"": "src"},
      packages=find_packages(where="src"),
      ext_modules=[ext1, ext2])
```

- __init__.py

The `__init__.py` file is empty. (Can e.g. import the F2PY modules here if desired)

- mod1.py

```py
def add(a, b):
  """ add inputs a and b, and return """
  return a + b
```

- funcs_m.f90

```fortran
module funcs_m
  implicit none
  contains
    subroutine add(a, b, c)
      integer, intent(in)  :: a
      integer, intent(in)  :: b
      integer, intent(out) :: c
      c = a + b
    end subroutine add
end module funcs_m
```

- plus2.f90

```fortran
subroutine plus2(x, y)
  integer, intent(in)   :: x
  integer, intent(out)  :: y
  y = x + 2
end subroutine plus2
```

- times2.f90

```fortran
subroutine times2(x, y)
  integer, intent(in)   :: x
  integer, intent(out)  :: y
  y = x * 2
end subroutine times2
```

- test_my_project.py

```py
import my_project.mod1
import my_project.oldf90
import my_project.modf90

print("mod1.add:            1 + 2 = ", my_project.mod1.add(1, 2))
print("modf90.funcs_m.add:  1 + 2 = ", my_project.modf90.funcs_m.add(1, 2))
x = 1
x = my_project.oldf90.plus2(x)
print("oldf90.plus2:        1 + 2 = ", x)
x = my_project.oldf90.times2(x)
print("oldf90.plus2:        3 * 2 = ", x)
```

#### Installing

Now, one can use `pip` to install the package. There are several [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15724093) to using `pip` (including ease of upgrading, or uninstalling) as opposed to `setup.py install` (but this can still be used for building the package for distribution!). From the directory containing `setup.py`:

```
> python -m pip install .
```

#### Testing

And then, to test the just installed package

```
> python test_my_project.py
mod1.add:            1 + 2 =  3
modf90.funcs_m.add:  1 + 2 =  3
oldf90.plus2:        1 + 2 =  3
oldf90.plus2:        3 * 2 =  6
```

This setup has been tested with success on Windows 10 (with ifort), on Ubuntu 18.04 (with gfortran) and on MacOS High Sierra (with gfortran), all with Python 3.6.3.

Comment: This looks great. I will test it. If I have multiple fortran files, I will have to use `Extension` for each of them separately. Is that right? Also, each of my fortran files contains a separate fortran module, and so it should ideally generate .so files for each separately.

Comment: As in the f2py docs, you have to create an `ext_i = Extension(...)` for each separate f2py module/.so you want to create, and then add them to `ext_modules=[ext_1,...,ext_i]` in setup.py. If a single f2py module consists of multiple Fortran source files, you list them under that particular `ext_i`'s `sources` argument. I'll update my answer when i have a moment

Comment: That works on Linux! I will just test this on Mac and Windows and then will accept the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, very happy with this setup myself, thanks to hours of experimenting/frustration, and eventually great documentation :-)

Comment: On Windows, do users need to have fortran installed for this installation to work?

Comment: Guess that depends if you distribute the source (then yes, and same for any OS), or pre built binaries (in which case you have to support that particular platform)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225212/discussion-between-jbdv-and-peaceful).

Comment: I have been trying hard to make my fortran files to use fortran modules in the same directory but installation throws error saying that modules not found. Any idea?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain your problem more specifically ito the example in the answer? I.e. which fortran files, what modules and which directories? Then I can try to have a look.

Comment: I want to split files in the directory containing fortran files into files containing modules so that several files would be able to use subroutines in these modules. Could you update your answer by adding explanation of how this could be achieved? The usual installation procedure throws errors if I simply move some subroutines to a separate file containing a module and `use` it in other files.

Comment: Adding a new `.f90` file at the same level as `funcs_m.f90`, that defines a new module, adding this file to `ext1`'s `sources` and making `funcs_m` `use` this new module, installs just as before for me. Could you add/describe an exact MWE to reproduce the problem you encounter?

Comment: Turns out that in setup.py, one must use correct file ordering in sources list. If a source code depends on modules in other files, those files must appear _before_ the source file!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a `setup.py` file like this (simplified version, keep only the relevant parts for building external modules)

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


class f2py_Extension(Extension):

    def __init__(self, name, sourcedirs):
        Extension.__init__(self, name, sources=[])
        self.sourcedirs = [os.path.abspath(sourcedir) for sourcedir in sourcedirs]
        self.dirs = sourcedirs

class f2py_Build(build_ext):

    def run(self):
        for ext in self.extensions:
            self.build_extension(ext)

    def build_extension(self, ext):
        # compile
        for ind,to_compile in enumerate(ext.sourcedirs):
            module_loc = os.path.split(ext.dirs[ind])[0]
            module_name = os.path.split(to_compile)[1].split('.')[0]
            os.system('cd %s;f2py -c %s -m %s' % (module_loc,to_compile,module_name))

setup(
    name="foo",
    ext_modules=[f2py_Extension('fortran_external',['foo/one.F90','foo/bar/two.F90'])],
    cmdclass=dict(build_ext=f2py_Build),
)
```

The essential parts for building an external module are `ext_modules` and `cmdclass` in `setup(...)`. [`ext_modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) is just a list of Extension instances, each of which describes a set of extension modules. In the `setup.py` above, I tell `ext_modules` I want to create two external modules with two source files `foo/test.F90` and `foo/bar/two.F90`. Based on `ext_modules`, `cmdclass` is responsible for compiling the two modules, in our case, the command for compiling the module is

```
'cd %s;f2py -c %s -m %s' % (module_loc,to_compile,module_name)
```

---

Project structure before installation

```
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── two.F90
│   └── one.F90
└── setup.py
```

Project structure after `python setup.py install`

```
├── build
│   └── bdist.linux-x86_64
├── dist
│   └── foo-0.0.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── two.F90
│   │   └── two.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│   ├── one.F90
│   └── one.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── foo.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
└── setup.py
```

The two source files `one.F90` and `two.F90` are very simple

`one.F90`

```
module test

  implicit none

  contains

  subroutine add(a)

    implicit none
    integer :: a
    integer :: b
    b = a + 1
    print *, 'one',b

  end subroutine add


end module test
```

`two.F90`

```
module test

  implicit none

  contains

  subroutine add(a)

    implicit none
    integer :: a
    integer :: b
    b = a + 2
    print *, 'two',b

  end subroutine add


end module test
```

After I installed the package, I can successfully run

```
>>> from foo.bar.two import test
>>> test.add(5)
 two           7
```

and

```
>>> from foo.one import test
>>> test.add(5)
 one           6
```

Comment: Thanks. I am testing this. My packages name contains a hyphen: `foo-bar` whereas actual directory names are `foo_bar` (with underscores). In setuptools.find_packages do I use `foo-bar` or `foo_bar`?

Comment: @Peaceful You're welcome. You need to rename `foo-bar` to `foo_bar` in that case (`foo_bar` works), otherwise although you can build the package, you can't import it because of `-` in the package name.

Comment: This does work for me! The only thing I had to change was to change `packages=setuptools.find_packages("foo")` to a list containing the modulename and submodule names `['foo', 'foo/bar']`. But before I accept this answer, as I said, I would also like to understand what is happening. I will then award the bounty!

Comment: @Peaceful Cheers! Check out my updated post, I provided a compact `setup.py` file.

Comment: Will this work even on Windows? Will this use even on Windows? Another change that I made was to use numpy.f2py in place of f2py.

Comment: @Peaceful I don’t have a PC, sorry, I don’t know whether this works on windows. You can test numpy.f2py, just change f2py to the compiler you want.

Comment: It has stopped working again! So all my fortran files are under a separate directory below top level directory. Do I need to replace `sourcedir=' '` by `sourcedir='fortran'`?

Comment: Also, I have 3 different fotran files, not just 1 as you have in your example.

Comment: When there are multiple fortran files, the .so files do not seem to get copied at the appropriate location.

Comment: @Peaceful so the approach stopped working when there are multiple files to compile (to independent .so files), but still works when there are only one to compile? I will update my post if this is the problem.

Comment: @Peaceful I have updated my post, the new `setup.py` allows build multiple modules in different dirs directly.